# VS 2012 RC Compiler issues

Tags: compiler-errors, windows-runtime, dependency-properties, converters

we are having VS2012 RC and getting many errors that are not in fact an errors.

Problem is that when there is an error in the project I must really look which one is it because I am getting a load of errors that will run just fine when I fix the real problem.

Issues:

1) The member xxx is not recognized or is not accessible ( in App.xaml, regarcing a DependencyProperty on a user control in defined Style ), example:

```
<Style .... TargetType="MyControl">
     <Setter Property="MyCustomProperty" ....
```

Problem here is that the DP is clearly public, yet I am having tens of erros regarding this case.

2) Converters not recognized at all, again in app.xaml file:

```
xmlns:converters="using:MyProject.Converters"

<converters:DebugConverter x:Name="DebugConverter" />
```

Error: The name DebugConverter does not exist in the namespace ...
It actually runs all converters fine, but errors are present anyway.

All of these errors only display in error list, it is not an issue when running the app, its just a huge problem when you have to locate a single real problem within 100+ errors.

Any advice here ? Closing files / restarting VS does not help, neither did resetting settings on VS.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance

Comment: Why are you still using the RC?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to RTM?

Comment: So - am I right in understanding that you're wondering why an error in your code leads to multiple, subsequent errors during compile?

Comment: In a way yes, but there are no links in errors whatsoever. Regarding RTM, you have to upgrade Win8 too, that's not going to happen.